# In Python can we use bitwise operators on data structures such as lists, tuples, sets, dictionaries? And if so, why?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

Now I understand the data in these data structures has to be of type integer for this to be viable but how would it work?

Suppose I had a list of lists or set with tuples in it; what would the result of that look like and what would it mean logically?

```
list_a = [[1,34,24],[12,727,2]]
list_b =[[12,727,2]]

some_list = list_a & list_b
# what would the above list look like?

set_1 = {(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)}

set_2 = {(1,3),(2,5),(6,7),(1,0)}

some_set = set_1 | set2
# what would the above set look like?
```

Could I use logical operators on the resulting data structures?

```
if some_value in set1 | set2:
    # do something
```

Comment: You cannot use logical operators on lists because the result is arbitrary. Furthermore, `list_a` and `list_b` are different sizes. What do you "want" the output of `some_list` to be?

Comment: For whether, why and how certain operations work on certain data structures, consult the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

Comment: The data doesn't need to be integers for this "to work"; in the case of a set, the data merely needs to be hashable so it can be part of a set, and then the `|` operation on the set does whatever it does (hint: set union).

Comment: I would want some_list to be a new list of lists where there are only values in list_a AND list_b.

Comment: Your examples would be better and easier with single items, not lists of list or sets of tuples.

Comment: @mojojojo47 sets work that way, with `__or__` overloaded to `set.union`. Lists do not.

Comment: Also: why not just try this? Drop into a repl and type your code -- see what happens.

Comment: `&` isn't defined for lists and you'll get an error when trying to use it. Whatever you *want* it to do, it won't do anything in practice…

Comment: Ok so what I want doesn’t work for list but it does work for sets? So, set1 | set2 is equivalent to set1.union(set2)

Comment: You can easily test it. It would be faster than asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't *bitwise* operators per se. They're *operators*, and each type can define for itself what it will do with them. The `&` and `|` operators map to the [`__and__` and `__or__` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) of an object respectively. Sets define operations for these ([intersection and union respectively](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)), while lists [do not](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations). Lists define an operation for `+` though (list concatenation).

Sooo… `set_1 | set_2` results in:

```
{(2, 3), (6, 7), (4, 5), (3, 4), (1, 0), (2, 5), (1, 3)}
```

As for the rest of the question: [Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#%22Unasking%22_the_question).